# SQL Select all columns from two or more Unrelated tables

Tags: sql

```
Table A
    A1 A2
1   1   2
2   2   2
3   1   3

Table B
  A1  A2
1  3   3
2  1   4
3  4   1 
4  5   0

Expected Result
Table C
   A1   A2
1  1    2
2  2    2
3  1    3
4  3    3
5  1    4
6  4    1 
7  5    0
```

Comment: check `UNION` operator

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables/12475851#12475851

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, consider marking it as the answer for future visitors of this question (done by clicking/marking the gray checkbox next to the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use union all

```
select a1,a2 from tbalea
union all
select a1,a2 from tbleb
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want possible duplicates to be in the output, use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT A1, A2 FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT A1. A2 FROM TableB
```

If you want duplicates to be grouped together, use `UNION`:

```
SELECT A1, A2 FROM TableA
UNION
SELECT A1. A2 FROM TableB
```